# Finding the median of 2 avl trees within O(logn) time

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

Currently I'm trying to solve the problem of finding the median of 2 AVL trees within O(logn) time, where n is total number of integers in both trees. In the problem, the integers are distinct and we can assume that n is odd, however we can't assume anything about how the integers are distributed between the trees. I've augmented the trees such that each node of the tree also stores the size of the subtree rooted at it. However, I'm not entirely sure where to go from there. Could anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: See also: [Find the median in two AVL BSTs in O(log(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60927275), [Find the median in two AVL BSTs in O(log(n))](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92200), [Find the median element of two AVL trees in O(logn)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/123398/19966)

Comment: Hello, ah yes n is the total of all of the elements in both trees

Comment: Thank you for letting me know I edited it into the questions. I looked into  the sources you provided, specifically this one https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/123398 and someone suggested to look into finding the kth element between 2 sorted arrays. However, I'm struggling to alter this algorithm to fit within the time complexity for a AVL tree. Could you please provide some suggestions as to how I could go about this?

Comment: Let me create a [chat room about *median in two AVL trees*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210781/median-in-two-augmented-avl-trees).